# Insert figure in a table, how to align figures with text in a table

Tags: tables, floats

I am inserting multiple figures into a table, and would like to make the following change:

1. center the text (1st column) in the cell (all the text currently are at the bottom)
2. center the figures (2nd and 3rd column) so that it doesn't cut the horizontal lines. The figures all have slightly different size. Is there a way to auto-adjust the height of each row so that all figures will fit it?
3. If possible, I would like to show some of the long text in two rows. For example, instead of :

   ```
   Inverting op-amp (linear amplifier)
   ```

   I want it to be in two lines, both horizontally centered in the cell:

   ```
   Inverting op-amp
   (linear amplifier)
   ```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is my latex code:

```
\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{  p{4.5cm}  p{5cm}  p{5cm}  }      % centered columns (3 columns) 
\hline\hline                                      %inserts double horizontal lines 
Building Block  & Circuits & Frequency Response \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading 
\hline
        Inverting op-amp
        (linear amplifier)
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockAB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockAC.png} \\ [1ex]
\hline  
        Integrator 
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockBB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockBC.png} \\
\hline  
        AC integrator with DC gain
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockCB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockCC.png} \\
\hline  
        Differentiator
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockDB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockDC.png} \\
\hline  
        AC differentiator with DC gain
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockEB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockEC.png} \\
\hline  
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A few basic circuit blocks and their frequency response for servo design.}
    \label{table4.2}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines containing LaTeX code by four spaces -- easily done by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the line above the editing window -- they will be pretty-printed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I made `\Includegraphics` (cap I) to insert a picture shifted down half its height.  I also used some `\linebreak`s and `\raggedright`s.

I also added some gap above/below the pictures, as requested with `\addstackgap`.  I can take an optional argument (default 3pt) to specify the gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{\sbox{\mybox}{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}\abovebaseline[-.5\ht\mybox]{%
  \addstackgap{\usebox{\mybox}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{  p{4.5cm}  p{5cm}  p{5cm}  }      % centered columns (3 columns) 
\hline\hline                                      %inserts double horizontal lines 
Building Block  & Circuits & Frequency Response \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading 
\hline
        \raggedright Inverting op-amp\linebreak
        (linear amplifier)
        & \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockAB.png}& \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockAC.png} \\ [1ex]
\hline  
        Integrator 
        & \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockBB.png}& \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockBC.png} \\
\hline  
        \raggedright AC integrator\linebreak with DC gain
        & \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockCB.png}& \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockCC.png} \\
\hline  
        Differentiator
        & \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockDB.png}& \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockDC.png} \\
\hline  
        \raggedright AC differentiator\linebreak with DC gain
        & \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockEB.png}& \Includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockEC.png} \\
\hline  
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A few basic circuit blocks and their frequency response for servo design.}
    \label{table4.2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven. I directly copy and paste your code to my document, which is a Thesis template, (I deleted two lines: begin and end document) but it won't compile. I got errors of "undefined control sequence" and "missiong number, treated as zero" for all lines that start with \Includegraphics. Not sure what it means. I would like to attach a picture of the errors, but didn't find where to attach it.

Comment: @Shun It is possible you stackengine.sty is out of date.  Could you check?  Current version is January 6, 2014
v3.24

Comment: I am currently using Texstudio 2.3 (SVN 2471), Using Qt Version 4.7.0. Do I have to check specifically the stack version?

Comment: Do I need to re-install the current version? That's frustrating... But thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @shun  If reloading the package is a pain for you, try adding `\usepackage{calc}` to the preamble instead.  However, I would otherwise need to know more details of the error.

Comment: Where should I add \usepackage{calc}? I added it before the line: \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}, but still got the same "undefined control sequence" and "missing number, treated as zero" errors (). Plus, I have one more error at the beginning of my chapter line 0, says, can be used only in preamble. Should I add it to the beginning of my document (thesis cover page) or first page of my current chapter?

Comment: @shun, you could also get the stackengine.sty from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine and place it in your working directory.  It will supersede whatever TeXstudio is using.  This would be easier than trying to blindly guess what the error is.

Comment: I download the file: stackengine.tex, and put it under my "dissertation" folder, restart TexStudio, but it still won't compile, and gave the same errors. : (

Comment: Did I put it in the wrong folder? I thought I should replace some old "stackengine" file by an updated one. I tried to search the entire local drive, but didn't find a file named "stackengine".

Comment: @Shun  A first step would be to see if you can compile my example given above.  Is this what you are trying to compile?  Place `stackengine.sty` in the same directory as the `.tex` file you are trying to compile.  And then compile.  Beyond that, I am limited in how I can assist you.

Comment: Hi Steven, I did what you said, and it worked! I finally realized how dumb I am. I should have add those "\usepackage" lines before the entire document, like before the cover page of my thesis. I also have the stackengine.sty and .tex files in my "dissertation" folder. It worked right away! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: However, I now have a new "floating" problem. I made the table to fit in a full page, it is then moved to the end of my chapter, not within the text flow as I'd like to. I tried to force it to be "here" by \begin{table}[h], but it didn't work. : ( seems to be a common problem, still working on that.

Comment: @Shun  You should search this site for that problem.  I'm sure there are several questions on it.  Generally, it might happen if the float is too large to fit on a page.  One "fix" is to issue a `\clearpage` immediately after the float, since a `\clearpage` will also clear out all pending floats.

Comment: Hi Steve, just to let you know that I've fixed the problem by using \begin{figure}[p], instead of \begin{figure}[h]. [p] creates a papge for floats large enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option; I used `m{<length>}` columns (from the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package) and the features provided by the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{  >{\raggedright}m{4.5cm}  m{5cm}  m{5cm}  }      % centered columns (3 columns) 
\toprule                                   %inserts double horizontal lines 
Building Block  & Circuits & Frequency Response \\  % inserts table heading 
\midrule\addlinespace[1.5ex]
        Inverting op-amp\\
        (linear amplifier)
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockAB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockAC.png} \\
\midrule\addlinespace[1.5ex]
        Integrator 
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockBB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockBC.png} \\
\midrule\addlinespace[1.5ex]
        AC integrator \\ with DC gain
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockCB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockCC.png} \\
\midrule\addlinespace[1.5ex]
        Differentiator
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockDB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockDC.png} \\
\midrule\addlinespace[1.5ex]
        AC differentiator \\ with DC gain
        & \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockEB.png}& \includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/servoblockEC.png} \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A few basic circuit blocks and their frequency response for servo design.}
    \label{table4.2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table is too wide for standard page layout, since no complete code was provided in the question, I assume some precautions are taken to avoid this in the actual document.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

[image]