# Center figures by default

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

Currently all of my figures look like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{my-figure}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to avoid specifying `\centering` in each figure, and instead would like to specify an alternative orientation if needed (rarely). Is this possible?

Comment: put the figure in a minipage

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160296/insert-figure-in-a-table-how-to-align-figures-with-text-in-a-table?rq=1

Comment: I don't understand the connection between your two comments. If you mean I should define a new command to includegraphics with centering, okay but I would rather not do that.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23078/how-can-i-automatically-center-an-image/53383#53383

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `floatboxreset` stuff with `floatrow`

Comment: Yes You are right just forgot to delete it